# How to loop through ActiveRecord values in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following columns in my table:

value1
value2
value3
value4
value5

I want to be able to loop through them like this:

```
<% for i in 1..5 %>
  <div><%= user."value#{i}"</div>
<% end %>
```

Of course this code doesn't work, so how can I get the value from an ActiveRecord object with a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `send` (see Ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332)).

Comment: No problem. Yes, Ruby is amazing! :)

Answer (score 7):

Wow, unless you really have a bad naming convention for your attributes, the `send` method is only going to get you halfway there.  Are your attribute names really numbered sequentially?

Here's how to loop through your attributes regardless of their names:

```
<% user.attributes.each do |name, value| %>
  <div>
    <%= name %>: <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will do all attributes.  It's entirely possible that his Rails application is interacting with some horribly formatted/named legacy database, and there are 5 fields named "contact1", "contact2" and so on.

Comment: This will certainly loop through all attributes, as advertised.  If you want to weed some out, you can easily do that with the select method.  I just didn't want him feeling like he has to name fields that way to be able to loop through them.

Comment: Like Mike said, there's some horrible stuff in the database that literally looks like this: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5. So yes, they are numbered sequentially. Good point though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `send` method to send a method name to any object as a string.  The example below is what you're looking for.

```
<% for i in 1..5 %>
  <div><%= user.send("value#{i}") %></div>
<% end %>
```